# How to backup Windows Explorer folders settings and set them via registry

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-registry

I'm customizing my system image and I want to add via registry some folder settings.
For example I want to group and sort files and folders by type.
Where is the registry key?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot set it manually in explorer via the options? This seems like a much easier way to do it.

Comment: Ok but I make many changes and usually I create a .reg file with all the tweaks.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found a solution to backup folders settings.

When we configure Folders Options and "Apply to all folders" our settings, Microsoft doesn't store them in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders, as it would be logical, but in the regkey of the folder we modified (e.g. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\3).

Now if you want to backup your settings:

1) Reset folders settings and delete bags keys (1,2,3...) under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\ (tutorials are available).

2) Run C:\Windows.

3) Make your customization.

4) Close folder.

5) Goto HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\###\Shell and right-click to export.

Now open the exported .reg file and replace the key [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\###\Shell] with this:

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7}]

Save.

This is very useful if you make unattended installation and want to add folders settings to your tweaks registry file.

:)

Answer (score 0):

After testing it, it seems this tweak works only for Current or Default User (no HKLM support).

It requires restart.

You can apply your settings with a registry file or a batch file at the end of Windows setup or you can try to integrate in the registry when you deploy your image.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get anything like the above proposed solution to work for the settings in File Explorer's "Folder Options" dialog.  But this works:

**NOTE**: As always, when messing with the registry, it is wise to back up (export) any keys that you will be changing prior to doing so!

First, determine your registry SID:

1. Run regedit (no need to run it as Administrator)
2. Expand the registry hive
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
   NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList which will display a list of users by their SID names
3. Expand each SID key and examine the ProfileImagePath value to
   identify which one is your user’s key
4. Right-click that SID key and select Copy Key Name, then paste the
   copied name into a Notepad or Word document.  The relevant part of
   the key name is the user’s SID, something like
   “S-1-5-21-982684679-592840582-1966211492-3399”

To save the current File Explorer settings:

1. Copy/paste the following key-path template into the same Notepad or
   Word document: HKEY_USERS\--your SID--\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
2. Copy the actual SID from your user’s ProfileImagePath key and paste
   it to replace the “--your SID--” part of the HKEY_USERS\...\Advanced
   key-path template
3. Copy the resulting HKEY_USERS\...\Advanced key-path to the clipboard
4. In regedit, if you haven’t already done so, set it to display its
   Address Bar (select View => Address Bar)
5. Paste the copied key-path into regedit’s Address Bar
6. Right-click the resulting
   HKEY_USERS\...\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
   key, select Export and give the export-file a name that clearly
   identifies what it is
7. And, one of File Explorer’s quirks is that its Navigation Pane's
   "Show Libraries" setting is stored in a different registry location,
   under the HKCU hive, so it has to be saved separately. Copy/paste
   the key-path
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID{031E4825-7B94-4dc3-B131-E946B44C8DD5}
   into regedit’s Address Bar.  (The actual "Show Libraries" setting is
   stored as that key’s System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree value but you
   will export the containing key itself.)
8. Right-click that key and select Export
9. Save the export file in the same folder location as File Explorer’s
   (general) settings export file, but you can’t make regedit append
   additional key data into an existing “.reg” file so you have to create a
   secondary file for the "Show Libraries" setting, named accordingly.

To restore previously saved settings:

1. Open File Explorer and go to the folder in which you previously
   saved the needed settings
2. For each of the exported “.reg” files (the general settings file and
   the "Show Libraries" setting file), execute the file by
   double-clicking it.
3. In the confirmation dialog, select Yes
4. In the “successfully added” dialog, select OK
5. **IMPORTANT**: for the new settings to take effect, you must sign out of
   Windows and sign back in!